# Pytest - connection to database

Tags: python, oracle, automation, pytest

I am automating with pytest, where the cases send parameters to a method in a class witch connects to a Databse and it returns a result, the problem I have is that the first case executes ok, but the second one returns FAILED test_002_create_desafio_base.py::test_impacto_base_subdominio - assert None == 20
, if I execute the second individually, the answers is ok, any idea what is the reason why it fails when I run the two tests? Does it have to do with the method that connects to the base?

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore::urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning')
def test_impacto_base_estado():
    response_create = api.post(url=CREATE_POST + "20",
                               data=json.dumps({"mecanismo": "SMS", "destino": "1111111111"}))
    response_json = response_create.json()["idOtp"]
    estado = conn.conexion(response_json, "estado")
    assert estado == "A"

@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore::urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning')
def test_impacto_base_subdominio():
    response_create = api.post(url=CREATE_POST + "20",
                               data=json.dumps({"mecanismo": "SMS", "destino": "1111111111"}))
    response_json = response_create.json()["idOtp"]
    subdominioId = conn.conexion(response_json,"subdominio_id")
    assert subdominioId == 20

'''
END PYTESTFILE

CONNECTION CLASS
'''
def conexion(self, idOtp, campo):
    try:
        cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=self._cliente)
        tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self._alias, self._numero, service_name=self._servicio)
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(self._usuario, password=self._password, dsn=tns)
    except Exception as error:
        print('No se puedo conectar a la base de datos. Error: ')
    else:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = cursor.execute("select " + f"{campo} from desafio where desafio_id = " + str(idOtp))
        datos = cursor.fetchone()
        return datos[0]'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call [`cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#using-cx-oracle-init-oracle-client-to-set-the-oracle-client-directory) once per process.  And don't forget that on Linux you still need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent *before* the Python process starts.